# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object using lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, python-re

I obtain the following error:
**TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object**
when applying this function to a dataframe column containing a Panda.core.series.Series object

```
activities['Nota'] = activities['Nota'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('<[^>]+>', '', x))
```

I don´t understund why this error is ocurring in this data frame but not in other similar ones

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I solved it converting the column to string:

```
activities['Nota'] = activities['Nota'].apply(lambda x: re.sub('<[^>]+>', '',str(x)))
```